# Bootstrap-vue: Change size of b-dropdown button

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

We implemented the bootstrap-vue in our application and we used the b-dropdown.

How can we change the button size? we want to change the button size to btn-sm

Below is the code, it didnt change the size of the button

```
<b-dropdown-item-btn button="btn-sm primary" right id="dropdown-1" class="m-md-2" style="display: inline;">

<i class="fa fa-gear"></i>

<b-form-select v-model="accounting_period_1" :options="accounting_period_options" @change="filterRevenueAndCosts()">
    
</b-form-select>
```

Question: How can we change the button size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This is how it could look after using `b-dropdown` with `b-dropdown-item` - set size to `sm` and set your `class`.

Here is how you can achieve that: *(I don't think I have to explain what I do)*

*Like this in your template:*

```
<div>
  <div>
    <b-dropdown size="sm" class="lang-dropdown" no-caret variant="light">
      <b-dropdown-item>
        Item 1
      </b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>
        Item 2
      </b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Like this in your style:*

```
.lang-dropdown .dropdown-menu { //you can also seperate these
   min-width: 4rem; //set your width here
}
```

Please let me know if this works out for you!

Comment: Can you give an example if I use the b-dropdown-item

Comment: updated it - hopefully it helps you now!

Comment: It worked, thanks !